# Checking if bitmap is recycled doesn't help to solve "RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap"

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I send bitmaps to my activity from Service (using `LocalBroadcastManager` and intent bitmap extra)

I set them to `ImageView` in activity like this:

```
if (!bitmap.isRecycled) {
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
}
```

When I don't need the service anymore I close it and release bitmap object kept in that service

But when I close the service I usually get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@fc4b896
```

So`bitmap.isRecycled` condition doesn't help here

Is there any safe method to set Bitmap to ImageView?

Comment: The comment regarding a potential duplicate seems to have been deleted, and there are no close votes on this question, so I have removed the material about a potential duplicate (it is not clear what was proposed as a duplicate anyway).

Comment: I do not advocate the use of the phrase "please read the question carefully". This may be interpreted by readers as your calling someone an idiot. It has a rather patronising and exasperated tone, and is best avoided. If you want to offer feedback on a potential duplicate, you can say "Thanks for the suggestion. I have checked that question {just now/already}, and I don't think it is a duplicate, because {reason}". That is much more likely to elicit a helpful conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)`, you should not recycle the bitmap after `setImageBitmap` because your imageView is still referencing and using that bitmap. You can recycle it when activity/fragment/view is destroyed.

Comment: So I have two options: set `setImageBitmap(null)` to `ImageVIew` before calling `bitmap.recycle()` or removing `bitmap.recycle()` line from the code. It seems it's better to use the second solution because Android >= 3.0 automatically releases such things

Comment: p.s. my activity is alive when I close my service. So it's not destroyed when I recycle that bitmap

Comment: Sure, you know your project the best :D

Answer (score 1):

You exception is telling you that **bitmap is already recycled** so no need to app check

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@fc4b896
```

instead just check for **null value**

Also check documentation why you got an error

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#isRecycled()

Comment: No, it says that you can't use a recycled image because we made it recycled a moment ago

Comment: I don't call `Bitmap.recycle` twice, only once. So I don't understand your answer, it doesn't make any sense

Comment: @user155 Which Studio version are you using.

Comment: Why do ask my Studio version? How it can help?

Comment: If you are using 3.0 and above version no need to call recycle() becasue GC will take care of it. If not work trim down your bitmap to SVG -> XML or WebP image

Comment: I googled about it. It's not about Studio, but Android OS Version. I guess I'll just remove `bitmap.recycle()` line from my project to solve this problem